# amfphp 2.2, index.php gives fatal error?

Tags: php, amf, amfphp

I downloaded the lastet AMFPHP version from

http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/downloads/

I tried this on Wamp and Xampp by hitting the default Amfphp URL, that is _http://localhost/amfphp-2.2/Amfphp/

And I put this on live server

http://cubixshade.com/pitv/amfphp/Amfphp/

but getting the same error

"Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in D:\xampp\htdocs\amfphp-2.2\Amfphp\Plugins\AmfphpMonitor\AmfphpMonitor.php on line 167"

I have added or changed nothing in the downloaded folder but still default index page or Amfphp entry point is not working.

Comment: your comment on the silex labs website is rude, but I'll try to help despite that. You should never have to open that url with your browser, just send requests to it. Admittedly it could be handled more elegantly and that shall be treated as a minor bug. I'll try to fix it and comment back here when it is done.

Comment: it was a quick fix, and it shall be included in the next maintenance release

Comment: I am sorry about my comment but i wasted my 4 or more hours on it, trying and searching where it went wrong. I have used AMF/PHP before and it used to give me such message like "this is the entry point of AMF/PHP" so that me frustrated.. I am sorry again.

Comment: apology accepted :-) So, did you get your system working?

Comment: Yes, I just commented those lines and things are good. And now the link displays a message like "This is the URL where you must send your requests to process them. In the documentation it is known as the 'entry point'. You might also see 'gateway' in some other documentation."