# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass - amfphp

Tags: codeigniter, amfphp

I am newbee for Amfphp+codeignitor, I am unable to see the answer for the question [amfphp 2.2, index.php gives fatal error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903476/amfphp-2-2-index-php-gives-fatal-error), Or it is not clear to me.

I followed the process mentioned here
http://www.nunomira.com/blog/2012/03/codeigniter-2-0-3-with-amfphp-2-0/

I am getting the same error - Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in D:\vhosts\site\application\libraries\Amfphp\Plugins\AmfphpMonitor\AmfphpMonitor.php on line 167

No Idea where i am doing the mistake.
http://localdomain.com/index.php/amf/gateway is the url i am trying.

How to rectify? what is the problem? if the problem is resolved, will i look service browser?

Experts please guide me on this...

Here is the code

Folder Structure

```
-controllers
 -amf
  -services
    -Testservice.php
  -Gateway.php

-libraries
 -Amfphp (Amfphp folder)
```

Gateway.php

```
<?php
require_once APPPATH . "/libraries/Amfphp/ClassLoader.php";
 class Gateway extends CI_Controller
 {
        function __construct()
        {       
                parent::__construct();
        }
        function index()
        {
                $config = new Amfphp_Core_Config();//do something with config object here
                $config->serviceFolders = array(dirname(__FILE__) . "/services/");
                $gateway = Amfphp_Core_HttpRequestGatewayFactory::createGateway($config);

                $gateway->service();
                $gateway->output();
        }
 }
```

Testservice.php

```
<?php

class Testservice extends CI_Controller {
       public function getMessage()
        {
            return array("param1" => "param1");
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are going to have to add some code for anyone to be able to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: I have added code, please look and let me know the next step. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

someone pointed out a similar problem and a fix has been made but not released yet. Could you try replacing your AmfphpMonitor.php code with this one?
https://github.com/silexlabs/amfphp-2.0/blob/master/Amfphp/Plugins/AmfphpMonitor/AmfphpMonitor.php

Comment: I have replaced as you suggested - it is working now. Now page says "Amfphp Entrypoint and This is the URL where you must send your requests to process them." Thanks alot

Comment: @Ariel The fix is not released yet!! Can you tell me when it will happen? For time being I have copied code from github.

Comment: Still not released yet, my apologies. I should have time to do a release at the end of the month. I'll update here when it's done